# List all bot commands from specific category

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a few commands from specific categories and I want to list them when user execute a command!
For example one of my commands:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
    name: "ping",
    description: "Bot websocket ping",
    category: "general",
    run: async (Raphy, message, args) => {
      message.channel.send(`${Raphy.ws.ping} ws ping`);
    }
}
```

I want to list commands in `General` category if user execute `!commands General`, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To list all commands from specific category in variable you can use this code:

#### v12

```js
if(args[0]) {
let list = ` `;
let commands = message.client.commands.array();
commands.forEach((cmd) => {
if(cmd.category == args[0].toLowerCase()) {
list = list.toString() + " **|** " + cmd.name.toString()
}
})
if (list == ` `) {
message.reply("Any commands in category or category does not exist!")
} else {
list = list.toString() + " **|**"
message.channel.send(`${args[0].toLowerCase()} category commands list: ${list}`)
}
}
```

#### v13

```js
if(args[0]) {
let list = ` `;
message.client.commands.each((cmd) => {
if(cmd.category == args[0].toLowerCase()) {
list = list.toString() + " **|** " + cmd.name.toString()
}
})
if (list == ` `) {
message.reply("Any commands in category or category does not exist!")
} else {
list = list.toString() + " **|**"
message.channel.send(`${args[0].toLowerCase()} category commands list: ${list}`)
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple filter will work:

```js
let categoryCmds = message.client.commands.filter(c => c.category === args[0].toLowerCase())
message.reply(categoryCmds.map(c => c.name).join(" **|** "))
```

This is very short syntax and is easy to modify to your liking.

Answer (score 1):

To make things cleaner, use `Collection#filter()` with `Collection#map()`, This will work with both v12 & v13. However, make sure you're running Node version 14 or higher.

```js
const category = args[0].toLowerCase?.() || 'unspecified';
const commandList = message.client.commands
   .filter(cmd => cmd.category == category)
   ?.map(cmd => cmd.name)
   ?.join(', ');
if (!commandList) {
   message.reply(`Commands with category ${category} not found`);
} else {  
   message.channel.send(`${category} command list: ${commandList}`);
}
```

[Array-Like Methods for Collections](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/collections.html#array-like-methods)